# How to pass an Image from GUI1 to GUI2 in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface

This must be easy but for some reasons I can't get this to work.
What I have is 2 GUIs namely GUI1 and GUI2.

In GUI1 I read and stored an Image in say `A`. It also has a PushButton. Now when I click this Button it should show that image in GUI2's axes1.

I tried `setappdata` and `getappdata` but it ends up giving error. I can't understand the syntax. I'm all new to MATLAB. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try `setappdata(0, ...` and `getappdata(0, ...`. `0` is the "root" of both GUIs, so both GUIs have access to it.

Comment: @Rotem That does the trick. Earlier instead of the root 0 i was messing around with handles.guiname and others. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setappdata` / `getappdata` are discussed in more detail below.

As mentioned in the comments, you can use `setappdata(0, ...` / `getappdata(0, ...` to assign/read data to/from the root object.

---

> Excerpted from [MATLAB User Interfaces - Passing Data Around User Interface](https://web.archive.org/web/20170908210339/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/2883/matlab-user-interfaces/9775/passing-data-around-user-interface). The original authors were [Suever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/670206/suever) and [Hoki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3460361/hoki). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/9775). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 2883 and example ID: 9775.

**Passing Data Around User Interface**

Most advanced user interfaces require the user to be able to pass information between the various functions which make up a user interface. MATLAB has a number of different methods to do so.

---

## [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)

MATLAB's own [GUI Development Environment (GUIDE)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/guide-tools-summary.html) prefers to use a `struct` named `handles` to pass data between callbacks. This `struct` contains all of the graphics handles to the various UI components as well as user-specified data. If you aren't using a GUIDE-created callback which automatically passes `handles`, you can retrieve the current value using [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html)

```
% hObject is a graphics handle to any UI component in your GUI
handles = guidata(hObject);
```

If you want to modify a value stored in this data structure, you can modify but then you must store it back within the `hObject` for the changes to be visible by other callbacks. You can store it by specifying a second input argument to [`guidata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html).

```
% Update the value
handles.myValue = 2;

% Save changes
guidata(hObject, handles)
```

The value of `hObject` doesn't matter as long as it is a UI component *within the same `figure`* because ultimately the data is stored within the figure containing `hObject`.

**Best for:**

- Storing the `handles` structure, in which you can store all the
  handles of your GUI components.
- Storing "small" other variables which need to be accessed by most callbacks.

**Not recommended for**:

- Storing large variables which do not have to be accessed by all
  callbacks and sub-functions (use `setappdata`/`getappdata` for
  these).

---

## [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html)/[`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html)

Similar to the `guidata` approach, you can use [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setappdata.html) and [`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getappdata.html) to store and retrieve values from within a graphics handle. The advantage of using these methods is that you can retrieve *only the value you want* rather than an entire `struct` containing *all* stored data. It is similar to a key/value store.

To store data within a graphics object

```
% Create some data you would like to store
myvalue = 2

% Store it using the key 'mykey'
setappdata(hObject, 'mykey', myvalue)
```

And to retrieve that same value from within a different callback

```
value = getappdata(hObject, 'mykey');
```

**Note:** If no value was stored prior to calling `getappdata`, it will return an empty array (`[]`).

Similar to `guidata`, the data is stored in the figure that contains `hObject`.

**Best for:**

- Storing large variables which do not have to be accessed by all
  callbacks and sub-functions.

---

## [`UserData`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html#bt9p4qp)

Every graphics handle has a special property, `UserData` which can contain any data you wish. It could contain a cell array, a `struct`, or even a scalar. You can take advantage of this property and store any data you wish to be associated with a given graphics handle in this field. You can save and retrieve the value using the standard `get`/`set` methods for graphics objects or dot notation if you're using R2014b or newer.

```
% Create some data to store
mydata = {1, 2, 3};

% Store it within the UserData property
set(hObject, 'UserData', mydata)

% Of if you're using R2014b or newer:
% hObject.UserData = mydata;
```

Then from within another callback, you can retrieve this data:

```
their_data = get(hObject, 'UserData');

% Or if you're using R2014b or newer:
% their_data = hObject.UserData;
```

**Best for:**

- Storing variables with a limited scope (variables which are likely to be used only by the object in which they are stored, or objects having a direct relationship to it).

---

## [Nested Functions](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/share-data-among-callbacks.html#bt9p4s2)

In MATLAB, a nested function can read and modify any variable defined in the parent function. In this way, if you specify a callback to be a nested function, it can retrieve and modify any data stored in the main function.

```
function mygui()    
    hButton = uicontrol('String', 'Click Me', 'Callback', @callback);

    % Create a counter to keep track of the number of times the button is clicked
    nClicks = 0;

    % Callback function is nested and can therefore read and modify nClicks
    function callback(source, event)
        % Increment the number of clicks
        nClicks = nClicks + 1;

        % Print the number of clicks so far
        fprintf('Number of clicks: %d\n', nClicks);
    end
end
```

**Best for:**

- Small, simple GUIs. (for quick prototyping, to not have to implement the `guidata` and/or `set/getappdata` methods).

**Not recommended for**:

- Medium, large or complex GUIs.
- GUI created with `GUIDE`.

---

## Explicit input arguments

If you need to send data to a callback function and don't need to modify the data within the callback, you can always consider passing the data to the callback using a carefully crafted callback definition.

You could use an anonymous function which adds inputs

```
% Create some data to send to mycallback
data = [1, 2, 3];

% Pass data as a third input to mycallback
set(hObject, 'Callback', @(source, event)mycallback(source, event, data))
```

Or you could use the cell array syntax to specify a callback, again specifying additional inputs.

```
set(hObject, 'Callback', {@mycallback, data})
```

**Best for:**

### - When the callback needs `data` to perform some operations but the `data` variable does not need to be modified and saved in a new state.